# Holomorphic but not the uniform limit of polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

For any compact set $K\subset\mathbb C$ with $\mathbb C\setminus K$ disconnected, construct a holomorphic $f:K\to\mathbb C$ such that $f$ is not the uniform limit of polynomials.

Mergelyan’s theorem states that: if $K\subset\mathbb C$ is compact, $\mathbb C\setminus K$ is connected, then any continuous function $f:K\to\mathbb C$ can be approximated uniformly on $K$ by polynomials.

So I am looking for a counterexample when we allow $\mathbb C\setminus K$ to be disconnected, and require $f$ to be holomorphic.

I have tried to exploit the fact that polynomials always integrate around a loop to $0$, but this needn't be the case for holomorphic functions. However, I haven't been able to construct a concrete example.

Comment: I mean, you're almost there. If $f$ were a uniform limit of polynomials, then any closed contour integral should vanish, since integrals and uniform limits commute. Now you just need to find a function where not every closed contour integral vanishes. You know such functions.

Comment: One component of $\Bbb C\setminus K$ contains a neighborhood of $\infty$. If $\Bbb C\setminus K$ is disconnected, it has some other component. For that component to be disconnected from $\infty$, there has to be a path in $K$ that surrounds it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick $w \in U$ bounded component of $\mathbb C\setminus K$ which must exist since $K$ compact mean $\mathbb C\setminus K$ contains the exterior of a large closed disc so the unbounded component is unique. Let $0<d=\max_{z \in K}|z-w|$ which is finite since $K$ compact.

Then $f(z)=\frac{1}{z-w}$ is holomorphic in a neighborhood of $K$ and assuming there are $P_n \to f$ uniformly on $K$ we can pick $m$ st $|P_m(z)-f(z)|<\frac{1}{2d}, z \in K$

Then $|(z-w)P_m(z)-1| < \frac{|z-w|}{2d} \le \frac{1}{2}$ for all $z \in K$. But now $g(z)=(z-w)P_m(z)-1$ is a polynomial so an entire function and $\partial U \subset K$ by the defintion of $U$ hence restricting $g$ to $\bar U$ (which is compact since $U$ bounded - here we use the hypothesis), we get that it attains its maximum modulus on $K$ and by the above that maximum is less than $1/2$, while $g(w)=1$ and that is a contradiction!